# SAT in real programming scenario

Tags: boolean-logic, smt

I read about SAT and SMT. I always wonder how it can be applied in real programming scenario.

Here is an example:

Given that `var a = 20; var b = a;` are true, we want to know if `b = 20` is true or false.

How should I turn it into boolean algebra expressions and apply SAT?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the simplest example using SMT-LIB 2.0 standard supported by many SMT solvers:

```
(declare-fun a () Int)
(declare-fun b () Int)
(assert (= a b))
(assert (= a 20))
(assert (= b 20))
(check-sat)
```

You can use http://rise4fun.com/z3 to experiment with it. It will respond "sat" meaning the assertions can be satisfied, meaning then b *can* be 20.

Then you can replace (assert (= b 20)) with (assert (distinct b 20)). Z3 will respond with "unsat" meaning it's not possible for b to be anything else.